# How would a sdbm hash function be implemented in C#?

Tags: c#, hash

How can a `sdbm` hash function (such as [this](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html)) be implemented in C# ?

Answer (score 3):

You can take the C code almost without changes:

```
uint sdbm( string str )
{
    uint hash = 0;
    foreach( char ch in str )
    {
        hash = ch + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Or did you think of something more sophisticated?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a C compiler set up so I can't test to see if it performs the same, but I *think* the following is correct:

```
private static ulong SBDM(string str)
{
    ulong hash = 0;

    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        hash = c + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;
    }

    return hash;
}
```

If you just need to get a hash of the string and it doesn't matter too much what the implementation is you can always do the `String.GetHashCode()`;

Answer (score 0):

The result from the hash differs between the C++ and C# implementation. I figured out that str parameter needs to be passed as a byte array.

```
private uint sdbm(byte[] str)
{
    uint hash = 0;

    foreach (char ch in str)
        hash = ch + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;

    return hash;
}
```

Call the method by converting the value to be hashed with the `BitConverter.GetBytes` method.

```
uint Hash = sdbm(BitConverter.GetBytes(myID));
```