# How to have a bigint hash for a string

Tags: string, integer

We have an alpha numeric string (up to 32 characters) and we want to transform it to an integer (bigint). Now we're looking for an algorithm to do that. Collision isn't bad (therefor we use an bigint to prevent this a little bit), important thing is, that the calculated integers are constantly distributed over bigint range and the calculated integer is always the same for a given string.

Comment: Ah, I thought only about a definition for an algorithm, but I can use PHP, Perl or Python for this.

Comment: So the questions is "How best to hash a string"?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what's needed? Are your strings completely arbitrary? Does it matter what int a given string is converted to? Does it need to be reversible?

Comment: Are you sure you need to hash into something larger than your language's standard int type? A good hashing function (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashing_function#Hash_function_algorithms) should be able to provide even distribution over the range of hash values, rendering the number of collisions quite low. Furthermore, if you're going to be using the resulting integers to put the strings into a hashtable, you'll need to decrease your range even more.

Comment: @Chris, OP has said collisions are permitted. In this case, it would not be reversible.

Comment: I think the downvote was uncalled for. It's not the best phrased question, but it's a real programming problem for OP.

Comment: BigInt is usually defined as having no upper limit so it’s meaningless to speak of its “range.” Your requirements are therefore confusing.

Comment: I have changed the title. I think this is somewhat in line with the post.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/142054) has a few. You'll need to port to 64bit, but that should be trivial. A C# port of SBDM hash is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954/how-would-a-sdbm-hash-function-be-implemented-in-c). Another page of hash functions [here](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html)

Answer (score 0):

Most programming languages come with a built-in construct or a standard library call to do this. Without knowing the language, I don't think anyone can help you.

Comment: A standard library call to turn an alphanumeric string (such as "123qza5") into a bigint? I think the question is quite clear what's needed.

Comment: I actually read the question as "interpret a string as a number", not "calculate a numeric hash for a string".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a "hash" should be the right description for my problem. I know, that there is CRC32, but it only provides an 32-bit int (in PHP) and this 32-bit integers are at least 10 characters long, so a huge range of integer number is unused!?

Mostly, we have a short string like "PX38IEK" or an 36 character UUID like "24868d36-a150-11df-8882-d8d385ffc39c", so the strings are arbitrary, yes.

It doesn't has to be reversible (so collisions aren't bad). It also doesn't matter what int a string is converted to, my only wish is, that the full bigint range is used as best as possible.